# Install LAPACK in windows 7 cannot find fortran compiler

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, fortran, lapack

I am trying to install Lapack on my Windows 7 64bit to use SciPy. I have run into many different answers about this topic but I have not seen anywhere anything about this.

I am following the guide from this website: https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/ from the section "Easy Windows Build". As the site states, I need to install CMAKE, Visual Studio and download lapack. I have installed "cmake-3.5.0-rc3-win32-x86", "Visual Studio 13" and minGW with all the packages that were available (just in case).

Finally, when I open the "cmake-gui" (as administrator) to perform the steps it says to build "Lapack" and I specify my source code folder (the lapack decompressed folder "lapack-3.6.0") and my output folder (a folder in Documents) and I click the Configure button I get the following error message:

```
Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid
```

I checked the log files of cmake and this is what I get:

CMakeError.log

```
Compiling the Fortran compiler identification source file "CMakeFortranCompilerId.F" failed.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gfortran.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Checking whether the Fortran compiler is Compaq using "-what" did not match "Compaq Visual Fortran":
gfortran.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-what'
gfortran.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Checking whether the Fortran compiler is NAG using "-V" did not match "NAG Fortran Compiler":
gfortran.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gfortran.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Determining if the Fortran compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Program Files (x86)/LAPACK/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project" "cmTC_249e8"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project" "cmTC_249e8"
```

CMakeOutput.log

```
The system is: Windows - 6.1.7601 - AMD64
Determining if the Fortran compiler is GNU succeeded with the following output:
# 1 "C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeTestGNU.c"

# 1 "<command-line>"

# 1 "C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeTestGNU.c"



void THIS_IS_GNU();





void THIS_IS_MINGW();
```

I have installed MinGW and I checked it is under the directory:

```
C:/MinGW
```

since I have also specified native compilers for CMAKE from inside the bin folder

```
gfortran.exe
gcc.exe
g++.exe
```

for Fortran, C and C++ respectively.

I checked online about the error in configuration process and from what I found out is that I need to have installed Visual Studio but I already have that.

Finally, I added the directory

```
C:\MinGW\bin
```

to the PATH variable.

Any suggestions as to why I cannot get to install LAPACK would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have declared your project as a Fortran project in the CMakeLists.txt: `enable_language (Fortran)`?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt where can I find this file?